# Time of lunar eclipse relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Would there be a change in time in terms of the length of time it take for a lunar eclipse to cross the moon as seen from earth compared to as what would be experienced from the moons surface?

Comment: You have a similar question [Lunar Eclipse and relativity](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/45294/7982) can you add a short explanation how this one is different, and in what ways the answer there applies here? *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, yes: For objects close to a large gravitational potential (the Earth), time moves faster than for objects far from it, or close to a smaller gravitational potential (the Moon). For example, Canadian astronaut Chris Hadfield mentioned, in a recent interview, being younger than he would be if he had stayed on the Earth—by about 0.006 seconds, mind you…

So yeah, the difference would be minimal, but “Moonlings” would experience a different duration for the eclipse than Earthlings.

Comment: A clock on Earth's surface *loses* about 2.19 seconds per century due to the Earth's gravity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation There's a graph showing the combined effects of gravity & orbital speed in the "Experimental confirmation" section.

Comment: So is there any way of finding data that would confirm this theory?

Comment: It’s not about the Moon, but it can be extrapolated to it: GPS satellites were launched without correction for time stretching due to the General Theory of Relativity. A correction had to be activated after a short time, as their time wasn’t the same as ground time.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this data

Comment: https://sci-hub.se/10.1063/1.1485583 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System#Relativity

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the gravity of the moon itself affect the general relativity equation. If so how can  we include this variable in the solution

Comment: @PierrePaquette Clocks in a gravitational field run *slower* not faster, so astronauts actually should grow older in space.due to the lack of gravity